# Замена слов в строке на ****

Tags: javascript, строки

друзья! Помогите решить вопрос. Суть, у меня есть инпут, куда пользователь вводит слова и по нажатию на кнопку, они записываються в строку , также есть текстареа, куда пользователь тоже вводить слова.При нажатии на кнопку Cenzor, слова которые идентичны словам, которые есть в строке от инпута должны замениться на ****, где * - это каждая буква. Я написал, код который заменяет целое слово на одну *, побывал делать перебор каждой буквы в внутреннем цикле, но тогда заменяется первое совпадение букв. Пожалуйста, помогите решить вопрос, буду при много благодарен, за ваше внимание!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  createWrapper();  
};

function createWrapper() {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.id = 'wrapper';
  document.body.append(wrapper);  
  wrapper.append(div(), input(), btnAdd(),  textarea(), cenzor());
  return wrapper;
}

function div () { // div for h1 and paragraph
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.append(p());
  return div;
}


function p() {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.id = 'p';  
  return p;
}

function btnAdd () {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'Add';
  btn.id = 'add';
  btn.onclick = add;
  return btn;
}

function input() {
  const inp = document.createElement('input');
  inp.id = 'inp';

  return inp;
}


function textarea() {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.style.display = 'block';
  textarea.id = 'textarea';
  return textarea;
}

function cenzor() { // кнопка, при нажатии на которою, должно происходить изменение тексареа
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'Cenzore';
  btn.onclick = cenzorCheck;
  return btn;
}

function add () { // обработчиик, которая добавляет слова из инпута в строку
  const inp = document.getElementById('inp');
  const p  = document.getElementById('p');
  if (inp.value) {  
  p.innerHTML += inp.value + ' ';
  }
}

function cenzorCheck() { //обработчик, для изменения слов,
  const p = document.getElementById('p');
  const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

// метод, который, возвращает совпадающие слова в строке инпута и текстареа
  let match = textarea.value.split(' ').filter(elem =>    
    p.textContent.split(' ').includes(elem));
    
    
    // ну и собственно, цикл, который делает не правильные изменения
    for (let i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {     
        textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(match[i], '*'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У строк есть встроенный метод `repeat()`, "умножающий" данную строку N раз:

`console.log( "Строка ".repeat(3) ); // "Строка Строка Строка "`

Ну можно было добавить это сюда:

`textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(match[i], "*".repeat( match[i].length ) );`

Но случайно по инерции переписал всё))

```js
initHTML();
setEventListeners();

function initHTML() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
   `<div id="wrapper">
      <p class="p"></p>
      <input class="inp">
      <button class="add">Add</button>
      <hr>
      <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
      <hr>
      <button class="censore">Censore</button>
    </div>`
  ); 
  // Незачем усложнять себе жизнь. Одной строкой это сильно проще, а разницы особо нет.
}

function setEventListeners(){
  let keyWords = []; // Вообще полезно хранить данные в переменных,
  // А HTML использовать только для их вывода.
  let elem = new Elements();
  
  elem.add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let word = elem.inp.value;
    if( !word || keyWords.includes( keyWords ) ) return;
    
    keyWords.push(word);
    elem.p.textContent = keyWords.join(" ");
  });
  
  elem.censore.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let reg = new RegExp( keyWords.join("|"), "ig" );
    elem.textarea.value = elem.textarea.value.replace(reg, function(match){
      return "*".repeat(match.length);
    });
    // Функция внутри replace получает в качестве аргумента совпадение целиком.
  });
  
  function Elements(){
    const root = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    const qs = str => root.querySelector(str);
    
    return {
      p: qs('.p'),
      inp: qs('.inp'),
      add: qs('.add'),
      censore: qs('.textarea'),
      textarea: qs('.textarea'),
    };
  }
}
```

Если бы в JS не было repeat, его не трудно повторить:

```js
String.prototype.repeat = function(times){
  var str = String(this);
  for( var i = 0, s = ""; i < times; i++ ){
    s += str;
  }
  return s;
}

console.log( "Bubu_".repeat(5) );
```

Comment: Ничего себе, у вас инерция!)
Огромное, спасибо, как всегда, решение было не сложным, но не достаток знания языка это демонстрирует на моем примере. Огромное вам спасибо, за помощь и информацию! Хорошего вечера и успехов!

Answer (score 0):

Вы из textarea value получаете, насколько я понял, надо из inp получать value.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  createWrapper();  
};

function createWrapper() {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.id = 'wrapper';
  document.body.append(wrapper);  
  wrapper.append(div(), input(), btnAdd(),  textarea(), cenzor());
  return wrapper;
}

function div () { // div for h1 and paragraph
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.append(p());
  return div;
}


function p() {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.id = 'p';  
  return p;
}

function btnAdd () {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'Add';
  btn.id = 'add';
  btn.onclick = add;
  return btn;
}

function input() {
  const inp = document.createElement('input');
  inp.id = 'inp';

  return inp;
}


function textarea() {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.style.display = 'block';
  textarea.id = 'textarea';
  return textarea;
}

function cenzor() { // кнопка, при нажатии на которою, должно происходить изменение тексареа
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'Cenzore';
  btn.onclick = cenzorCheck;
  return btn;
}

function add () { // обработчиик, которая добавляет слова из инпута в строку
  const inp = document.getElementById('inp');
  const p  = document.getElementById('p');
  if (inp.value) {  
  p.innerHTML += inp.value + ' ';
  }
}

function cenzorCheck() { //обработчик, для изменения слов,
  const p = document.getElementById('p');
  const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')
  
// Здесь была ошибка, вы перебирали textarea, и получали пустой массив
  let match = textarea.value.split(' ').filter(elem =>    
    p.textContent.split(' ').includes(elem));


    // из-за пустого массива на предыдущем шаге здесь на выходе получали 1 звезду.
    //тут укажите, как добавлять новые значения, просто заменять старые или добавлять к старым =+
    match.forEach((item)=> {
      textarea.value = item.split("").map(()=>'*').join("");
    })
}
```

Comment: Если есть совпадение - из textarea весь текст заменяется на N звездочек) А надо бы только совпадающие.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME он так и работает. Просто он смотрит не в значение textarea, а в input ->если находит совпадение в P, то звездочки записывает в textarea. Справедливости ради, у вас тоже ошибка :) Вы буквы сравниваете, хотя ТС писал "если находит слово".  Для примера, добавьте в своем варианте любую букву, а потом "зашифруйте" слово, в котором есть эта буква.